# ESP32 - What are the negative consequences using min_spiffs partition table?

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, spiffs

Maybe my question is trivial but I'm wondering why spifss should have a bigger space than bare minimum. Is min_spiffs configuration a good choice for all kind of applications?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data fits into the file system (note that it's only around [75% effective](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/spiffs.html#notes)), you can allocate as little space for it as you want. The problem is load balancing the writes. The Flash in an Espressif module has a limit of 100000 writes per page. If your application writes a lot of data, this load can be spread over a larger amount of pages by creating a bigger SPIFFS partition. So it really depends on how often and how much data your application is writing over the lifetime of your device. If you create a small partition and write lots of data, the Flash pages allocated for SPIFFS can exceed 100000 writes and are no longer guaranteed to work.